# control orientation by sensor on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile

I painfully found out today that

> setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);

Does not work properly on the latest Samsung devices.

I want to be able to set screen orientation by the state of the sensor, meaning that even if the device has portrait only set (on device level), if the user rotates the device to landscape my app should change configuration - Reload activity with the proper layout.

`SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR` works fine on any other device, and on old Samsung devices. New Samsung devices do all sort of crazy layout behaviour with that setting.

Comment: Do you know a workaround for this issue with Samsung devices?